# sentence structure check

Tags: grammar

All right, but I still need to know what are the requirements necessary to meet the requirements of that program in relation of language proficiency, age and work experience?, Keeping in mind that I have Bachelor's degree in English language.

Comment: Proof-reading is off-topic for this site, but I would shorten the wordy and repetetive "what are the requirements necessary to meet the requirements of that program..." to "what the requirements of that program are..."

Comment: I can't work out what the question is, or even if there is a question here.